# Running an Anova in R. Is this running correctly?

Tags: r, anova

I am attempting to run an anova test on this data.

```
>    Weeks Voles Rodents Treatment
1        1     1       7         A
2        2    13      72         A
3        3     9     153         A
4        4    18     211         A
5        5    16     226         A
6        6    28     273         A
7        1     1      25         B
8        2     8      58         B
9        3     7     109         B
10       4     6     125         B
11       5     0     110         B
12       6     1     137         B
13       1     0      28         C
14       2    18      72         C
15       3     7     117         C
16       4    36     162         C
17       5    32     153         C
18       6    14     117         C
```

I am trying to examine if the treatment and weeks are an effect on the number of rodents. So is the number of rodents affected by the treatment over a 6 week period. The code I used to run this was

```
Rodents<- aov(Rodents ~ Treatment + Weeks, data = dat)
summary(Rodents)
```

But is that correct for what I am trying to examine? I never ran an anova before and the fact that it worked on the first time makes me worried. I have poor coding skills. Is there a better R anova code to run? is the one I'm using okay? Thanks in advance and I apologize for rambling on.

Comment: You mention `Primary` there but I don't see that in your data

Comment: Oh sorry, I changed it to try and make more sense for the post.I just updated it in the code

Comment: The "correctness" of a statically model is really a statistics question, not a programming question. It all depends on the assumptions you want to make to model your data. If you want statistical advice, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead of Stack Overflow. if the code runs without error then it's not really a programming problem.

Comment: MrFlick is absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is ok if you ensure that your week is a continuous variable. This means you have to assume that there is linear trend between `weeks` and `rodents`.You have only 1 observation per week:

```
table(dat$Treatment,dat$Weeks)
   
    1 2 3 4 5 6
  A 1 1 1 1 1 1
  B 1 1 1 1 1 1
  C 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Now if you look at the data, linear trend might be ok.. hard to tell with just n=1 for each week / treatment:

```
dat$Treatment = factor(dat$Treatment,levels=c("A","B","C"))
plot(Rodents ~ Weeks,data=dat,col=Treatment)
legend("topleft",fill=1:3,legend=levels(dat$Treatment))
```

[image]

Seems like the dependent variable changes with week, and most likely A is slightly more than B and C. I guess this is what you get from the anova:

```
Rodents<- aov(Rodents ~ Treatment + Weeks, data = dat)
summary(Rodents)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Treatment    2  13109    6554   4.435   0.0322 *  
Weeks        1  52330   52330  35.407 3.55e-05 ***
Residuals   14  20691    1478
```

Your data:

```
dat = structure(list(Weeks = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), Voles = c(1L, 13L, 9L, 18L, 
16L, 28L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 18L, 7L, 36L, 32L, 14L), 
    Rodents = c(7L, 72L, 153L, 211L, 226L, 273L, 25L, 58L, 109L, 
    125L, 110L, 137L, 28L, 72L, 117L, 162L, 153L, 117L), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
18L))
```

Comment: Ahh okay I think I understand what you are saying. How I had the data, it ran the weeks not as a continuous variable. With how you formatted it, it is showing the change with treatment over time.

Comment: How about adding a `Treatment:Week` interaction if you suspect different treatment have different effects of the number of rodents through out the week?